# Python: formulas as elements of matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I am calculating total cost of shipment for different countries. As input I have an initial fee and origin country and destination country. As output I would like to get the total cost. 
Of course depending on the origin and destination country the formula to calculate the total cost varies.

To solve this solution I thought I should use a matrix which contains the formulas needed to apply to calculate the total cost.
My problem is I really dont know how to make matrix which contains formulas. Could you point me in the right direction, please?

Just to make it more understandable I made a sketch of the matrix I was thinking of below.

Input function:

```
totalCostCalc(init_cost, origin_country, destination_country)
```

Calculation matrix:
[image]

The different colors of matrix elements show the different formulas or functions applied.

Could you please help me by showing how to start, or something similar as I am really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you will prefer any other solution, but making such a matrix of formulae isn't a good thing, I would say.

I think you should create a `dictionary` of contries as `key` and their `value` being the continents.

So, whenever the `totalCostCalc` function is called, you need to just check three conditions.

```
def totalCostCalc(init_cost, origin_country, origin_country_fee, destination_country, destination_country_fee)
    if (origin_country == destination_country):
        return init_cost
    elif (d[origin_country] == d[destination_country]):
        return init_cost*origin_country_fee*destination_country_fee
    else:
        return init_cost*origin_country_fee*destination_country_fee*continent_fee
```

where `d` is the dictionary defined as `d = {'Germany': 'Europe', 'Hungary': 'Europe', 'China': 'Asia'}`.

Comment: This is a good start! Although I'd also put the fees in the dictionary for each country. The signature of the function ends up being too long.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel I was also thinking the same. But I don't know how is the OP storing it.

Comment: Anyhow, this is a start ;)

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Also, I think the OP must have got sufficient hint to get started. :)

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Will work it out this way. Thank you.